# InvalidArgumentError: input_14:0 is both fed and fetched

Tags: filter, deep-learning, visualization, conv-neural-network

I want to Visualize my CNN filters on every layer. I write a code for this but this is giving me some error.I want to see filter images of every layer and also want to see the heat maps of the area which my neural net use the most to predict the particular label. By doing this I am able to understand the working of my cnn and do further work on my model for better results

I searched it on google but I found mostly sited with theory but i need to see code for the solution

```
x = Conv2D(64,(3,3),strides = (1,1),name='layer_conv1',padding='same')(input)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2),name='maxPool1')(x)



x = Conv2D(64,(3,3),strides = (1,1),name='layer_conv2',padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2),name='maxPool2')(x)

x = Conv2D(32,(3,3),strides = (1,1),name='conv3',padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2),name='maxPool3')(x)


x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(64,activation = 'relu',name='fc0')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = Dense(32,activation = 'relu',name='fc1')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = Dense(2,activation = 'softmax',name='fc2')(x)

model = Model(inputs = input,outputs = x,name='Predict')




a=np.expand_dims( X_train[10],axis=0)
a.shape
from keras.models import Model
layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]
activation_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=layer_outputs)
activations = activation_model.predict(a)
```

I am getting this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-249-119bf7ea835a> in <module>()
      2 layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]
      3 activation_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=layer_outputs)
----> 4 activations = activation_model.predict(a)
      5 
      6 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks)
   1185                                             verbose=verbose,
   1186                                             steps=steps,
-> 1187                                             callbacks=callbacks)
   1188 
   1189     def train_on_batch(self, x, y,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in predict_loop(model, f, ins, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks)
    320             batch_logs = {'batch': batch_index, 'size': len(batch_ids)}
    321             callbacks._call_batch_hook('predict', 'begin', batch_index, batch_logs)
--> 322             batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
    323             batch_outs = to_list(batch_outs)
    324             if batch_index == 0:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2919                     return self._legacy_call(inputs)
   2920 
-> 2921             return self._call(inputs)
   2922         else:
   2923             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _call(self, inputs)
   2873                                 feed_symbols,
   2874                                 symbol_vals,
-> 2875                                 session)
   2876         if self.run_metadata:
   2877             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals, run_metadata=self.run_metadata)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _make_callable(self, feed_arrays, feed_symbols, symbol_vals, session)
   2825             callable_opts.run_options.CopyFrom(self.run_options)
   2826         # Create callable.
-> 2827         callable_fn = session._make_callable_from_options(callable_opts)
   2828         # Cache parameters corresponding to the generated callable, so that
   2829         # we can detect future mismatches and refresh the callable.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _make_callable_from_options(self, callable_options)
   1469     """
   1470     self._extend_graph()
-> 1471     return BaseSession._Callable(self, callable_options)
   1472 
   1473 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __init__(self, session, callable_options)
   1423         with errors.raise_exception_on_not_ok_status() as status:
   1424           self._handle = tf_session.TF_SessionMakeCallable(
-> 1425               session._session, options_ptr, status)
   1426       finally:
   1427         tf_session.TF_DeleteBuffer(options_ptr)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    526             None, None,
    527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InvalidArgumentError: input_14:0 is both fed and fetched.
```

I tried by removing some layers and adding some layer but it didnt help me. I found very less code on google.

Answer (score 0):

To access any layer's output, you can use `function` in `keras`, something like this:

```
from keras import backend as K
last_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                  [model.layers[-1].output])
layer_output = last_layer_output([x])[0]
```

So to access all layer's output, you can create as many such function as follows:

```
outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]
functors = [K.function([model.input, K.learning_phase()], [out]) for out in outputs]

layer_outs = [func([x_test[:4], 1.]) for func in functors]
```

Note: `keras-function` produce one output for one layer.

More you can read it [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer)

Comment: I am really thankful to you for keeping my problem under consideration. I have another solution for this which I got from an article that seems to be easy for beginners. I will try this too thank you again brother

Answer (score 0):

with this model my problem is not solving so I make a simple model and use keras fucntions to get layers output and this is easy as compared to my previous model.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16,kernel_size = (5,5),activation = 'relu', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-8)))
model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size = (5,5),activation = 'relu', activity_regularizer = regularizers.l2(1e-8)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(3,3))
model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size = (5,5),activation = 'relu', activity_regularizer = regularizers.l2(1e-8)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(3,3))
model.add(Conv2D(128,activation = 'relu',kernel_size = (3,3),activity_regularizer = regularizers.l2(1e-8)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(64,activation = 'relu',activity_regularizer = regularizers.l2(1e-8)))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(64,activation = 'relu',activity_regularizer = regularizers.l2(1e-8)))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(2,activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr = 0.001,clipnorm = 1,momentum= 0.9), metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs = 10 ,batch_size = 16,validation_data=(X_test,y_test_Categorical))
model.summary()

#a is my one example from test set
a=np.expand_dims( X_train[10],axis=0)
a.shape
layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]
activation_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=layer_outputs)
activations = activation_model.predict(a)

def display_activation(activations, col_size, row_size, act_index): 
    activation = activations[act_index]
    activation_index=0
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(row_size, col_size, figsize=(row_size*2.5,col_size*1.5))
    for row in range(0,row_size):
        for col in range(0,col_size):
            ax[row][col].imshow(activation[0, :, :, activation_index])
            activation_index += 1
display_activation(activations, 4, 4,0)
```

by doing this I am able to get my output